# “/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-mt" installing pycuda 2011.2.2

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, libraries

Trying to install PyCuda I followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123546/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lboost-python-mt-error-when-installing-pycuda-2011-2) as I ran into that problem but unfortunately I am still getting the error:

```
c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp/cuda.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp/bitlog.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/wrapper/wrap_cudadrv.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/wrapper/mempool.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/wrapper/wrap_curand.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lboost_python-mt-py27 -lboost_thread-mt -lcuda -lcurand -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pycuda/_driver.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py27
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcurand.so when searching for -lcurand
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I found the linking file `libboost_python-mt` in `/usr/lib/` but it seems referencing `/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py26` which does not exist. Though `/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py27` does ..

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the *"boost-python-libname"* argument for **configure.py** from:

```
--boost-python-libname=boost_python-mt-py
```

to:

```
--boost-python-libname=boost_python-mt-py27
```

Adding the **27** will link directly to the library you say you have installed

This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 with manual CUDA 5.5 install (not from the ubuntu repository).